# Did Ramakrishna say that he will take birth again?

Tags: ramakrishna

I read story that Ramakrishna said that he would once again take birth after 100 years or 200 years. Is it recorded in detail in any of the authentic biographies?

Comment: Where did u read?

Comment: @AkshayS RamaKrishna lilamrita published by RamaKrishna mutt in my local language

Comment: You know that Lilamrita is the ref .. why are u asking then? People who will answer will probably quote the same text

Comment: @Rickross it is brief, it says it is taken from elsewhere which I can't recollect now. That's why I asked for a detailed account of that story. I don't have any of these books right now & I read very long ago.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is mentioned in *Gospel of Sri Ramakrishna* and  *Sri Ramakrishna The Great Master by Swami Sardananda*

Gospel / Volume 2 / The Master On Himself And [His Experiences](http://www.ramakrishnavivekananda.info/gospel/volume_2/44_master_on_himself.htm):

> Master - It will be sufficient for the youngsters who come here if they know only two things. If they know these, they will not have to practise much discipline and austerity. First, who I am, and second, who they are. Many of the youngsters belong to the inner circle. Those belonging to the inner circle will not attain liberation. **I shall have to assume a human body again, in a northwesterly direction.**

Part 2 - As The Spiritual Aspirant / Epilogue To The Story Of The [Master's Sadhanas](http://www.ramakrishnavivekananda.info/sriramakrishna_thegreatmaster/srkgrtmaster_files/Sri%20Ramakrishna%20-%20The%20Great%20Master-33.html):

> Pointing to the north-western direction, he told us over and over again that he would have to come to that region on the next occasion. Some assert that he gave them the time of his next advent and said, "I shall have to come to that side in two hundred years. Many will be liberated then. Those who do not get liberation at that time, will have to wait very long for it thereafter."

Comment: Which region? in Bengal?

Comment: He told that He will come in form of baul with 'hnuko-kalke in hand and so i think He meant Bengal. Some disciple,s like Bijnananandaji i think mentioned He told He wd come after 100 years

Comment: In Swapnajiban by Anndathakur, we get Sri RK woukd come back after 23 years of His demise